# Updating the count of 'many' items in a Table using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, count, one-to-many

I have a simple One to Many relationship in my DB. Here are the corresponding Classes:

```
class Department
{
    int deptId;
    int count; //This corresponds to the total number of Employees in a department
    List<Employee> employees; //An employee belongs to only one department
}

class Employee
{
    int employeeId;
    Department dept;
}
```

In order to keep the `count` updated, I am setting the `count` on each `CUD` operation. Is there an automatic way to update the `count` on each Add/Delete of an employee to the Department? (An annotation/restriction or something?)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you keep a global variable with the employees count ?
Adding a method that returns the size of the employees list is safer and much more elegant.

```
public class Department {

   private int deptId;
   private List<Employee> employees;

   public int getCount() {
      if (employees == null) {
         return 0;
      }
      return employees.size();
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Why are you calm only on stackoverflow? :P

Comment: It's just that I don't want to load all the employee rows on each department access. FetchType is LAZY. However, I need to show the summary (employee count) on each Dept read.

Comment: Then you should take a look at the "Extra Lazy" fetching startegy : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching. If you use annotations you just need to add @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no automatic way in Hibernate.

Anyway, generally this risks to produce wrong results. What will happen if one user adds an employee and at the same time a second user removes an other employee? (This case still can be handled in Hibernate.) Or what happens if the dba adds some employees by an insert statement or loads data from a backup?

In the view of the database model this is superfluous information and should be omitted. Instead a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE dept =:deptId` should be used.

The only reason for the count column is if you need the count very often and you have performance problems with a select(*). For this special case there is no Hibernate automatism.

Edit:

I've just seen Overmeulens answer now. That also is working. If you only need the count, then `SELECT COUNT(*)` (also can be done in HQL) is faster, if you need the employee records anyway then Overmeulens solution has better performance.

Comment: I know it will be difficult to maintain the sanctity of the count field.However, I want to avoid the select count(*) on each get. [The writes will always be using Hibernate and external action by DBA will not be allowed.]

Comment: I just wanted to explain why there probably is no automatism. You can continue with your solution, count manually (or execute `SELECT COUNT(*)` after each add or remove of an employee - it won't happen often anyway) and either select the department for update or introduce a version column in the department table (you should have it anyway), which is incremented whenever an employee is added or removed.